# Logged off users still showing as "Online" on views, but fine on Who's Online module

Tags: views, users

I am using a view to show which users of the website are online or offline. I am using user:online field and global PHP field combination with views PHP. Everything works perfectly.

However, when a user logs off, they are shown online forever.

The code I use for global PHP is the following.

```
<?php print_r ($row->login); ?>
```

Comment: Are you caching your views? If yes, then that explains it.

Comment: Thanks, but I dissabled cashing, and I also user Chrome with no cache for testing. Not working.

Comment: It's not clear, if you are using user:online, why you are showing code accessing `$row->login`.

Comment: Hi Kiamlanluno, what code should I put in there? I want users that are online (logged in) to show up? Thanks